# ctest does not find valgrind

Tags: c++, cmake, valgrind, ctest

Calling

```
ctest -j4 -DCTEST_MEMORYCHECK_COMMAND="/usr/bin/valgrind" -DMemoryCheckCommand="/usr/bin/valgrind" --output-on-failure -T MemCheck
```

says

```
Memory checker (MemoryCheckCommand) not set, or cannot find the specified program.
```

Why doesn't it find valgrind automatically nor when specified manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As described on the [CTest Wiki page](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/ctest/Generating-Testing-Files), CTest reads the location of the memory check command (among other settings) from a file `DartConfiguration.tcl` in the build directory. One way to create the dart configuration file is to simply include the CTest CMake module in your CMakeLists.txt:

```
include (CTest)
```

The CTest module will find your valgrind installation in `/usr/bin` and put a variable `MemoryCheckCommand` pointing to it in the `DartConfiguration.tcl` file.

Answer (score 0):

After install valgrind by "apt-get install valgrind", the error is gone.
The Error was
"Memory checker (MemoryCheckCommand) not set, or cannot find the specified program.
Errors while running CTest"

New result

**Processing memory checking output:
1/1 MemCheck: cpp_test    Defects: 1
MemCheck log files can be found here: (<#> corresponds to test number)
Memory checking results:
Memory Leak - 1**

The detail log is logged
/build/Testing/Temporary# cat MemoryChecker.1.log

Showed detail leaking information

**HEAP SUMMARY:
in use at exit: 8,000 bytes in 1 blocks
total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 80,704 bytes allocated**

you should start over from **cmake ..** , **cmake --build .** and **ctest -T memcheck**